# Media player doesn't actually play on real device

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using android media player, on emulator I can hear it playing but on real device it doesn't work.

I have

```
MediaPlayer.Create(Android.App.Application.Context, Resource.Raw.gong);
```

gong set at embedded resource I have also tried android resource

Comment: Can you please share more detailed information? Are you using the code in the Xamarin.Android project? Can you share the `gone` resource with us?

Comment: this is on android part and I sm using Xamarin forms

Comment: Can you have a try with MediaPlayer.SetDataSource? `gong` should be set as android resource.